# remote debugging a jnlp application with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm trying to debug a web start application using IntelliJ 10 (running on Win7).

I read both SO:

- [remote debugging a jnlp application with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669673/remote-debugging-a-jnlp-application-with-eclipse)
- [How can I debug applications under Java Web Start (JNLP) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686061/how-can-i-debug-applications-under-java-web-start-jnlp)

It seems like I'm missing something.
I've tried to run it from command line, or adding the arguments into the jnlp file but no matter what I do I get an *`Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"`* Error.

How can I debug a web start app?

Comment: are you sure you are trying to connect to the same debug port your configured for your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's stupid, but once I changed the port from 5000 to 5005 it all works.