# Remote debug jnlp with IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to debug a jnlp with IntelliJ but it keeps telling me

```
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.connectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

First I start the jnlp via command line with

```
javaws -J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 http://server:port/app.jnlp
```

afterwards I run the remote debug configuration in IntelliJ and I get the aforementioned exception

Screenshot of the IntelliJ configuration and the command line:
[image]

I've already read following questions:

- [Debugging JNLP started application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899675/debugging-jnlp-started-application)
- [How can I debug applications under Java Web Start (JNLP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686061/how-can-i-debug-applications-under-java-web-start-jnlp)
- [remote debugging a jnlp application with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678206/remote-debugging-a-jnlp-application-with-intellij)
- [Remote debugging java web start under JVM 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668723/remote-debugging-java-web-start-under-jvm-1-8)

but their answers (add arguments via Java control panel, set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable, ...) don't seem to work for me.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

I'm using IntelliJ 2017.1.5 and JDK1.8.0_121 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you see port 5005 open using TcpView, netstat or similar tools? Does it belong to your jnlp app? Did you try some other port? Can you telnet to `localhost 5005`?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Nope. `telnet localhost 5005` says something like  `Can not create connection with host on port 5005`

Comment: So, you need to figure out why your debug options do not have any effect, it has nothing to do with the IDE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That's a start. Thanks. What do you mean by 'Does it belong to your jnlp app'? Do I need to configure port 5005 inside the jnlp? And yes, I tried different ports.

Comment: Apps like [TcpView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) will list the ports open for connection and will show which app the port was open by. That is what I mean by "belongs to".