# How to debug Java WebStart Application

Tags: java, debugging, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I debug applications under Java Web Start (JNLP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686061/how-can-i-debug-applications-under-java-web-start-jnlp)

I have a JWS application, that runs fine when I simply run it with Java Web Start, however when I try and debug it, using netbeans (jws-debug), it immediately exits.

If I run it as an application (without JWS) however, I'm able to debug it perfectly well.

How can I  debug it as a JWS application?

Comment: I always thought Java Webstart execution was close to identical with regular execution.

Comment: So did I, but for some reason JWS debugging doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to debug it as "JWS" instead of as a normal application?

Comment: note that javaws may decide to fork a new JVM for multiple reasons.  enable java console to see exactly what happens.

Comment: @Varun Madiath: Agreed with Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, run in console and see what you get.

Comment: aioobe - I've got to debug it as a JWS because I'm finding behaviour that is only triggered when the application is run through JWS.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I have the java console enabled, and when I run it as a normal application it appears displays all information. However that doesn't happen when I try and debug it.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - I think you're right about javaws forking a new JVM, because even when I run it normally, netbean says "build sucessful" before the application has finished. While it doesn't do this when I run it as a regular application.

Comment: @aioobe, the Java WebStart process is quite complex and includes e.g. a security manager.

Comment: @varun, how do you try to debug it and what exactly is listed in java console at trace level.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - I'm attempting to debug it by hitting the debug button in netbeans. I appended the following to the JVM arguments in the netbeans configuration dialog. `-verbose -J-Xdebug -J-Xnoagent -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=8200`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly ended up using the information on the accepted answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686061/how-can-i-debug-applications-under-java-web-start-jnlp). The trick was to stop attempting to debug the application as a local application, and instead to use the Netbeans remote debugger which ended up working quite well.