# Debugging JNLP started application

Tags: java, swing, debugging, jnlp

I created a Java desktop-application (using Swing) and am now trying to make it work by starting it from the net using JNLP. The application works fine when I start it from the terminal, but as soon as I launch it from JNLP, it does not close. I have to manually kill the process every time.

I read that there might be a problem if my `JFrame` uses `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` as the default close-operation, but it doesn't. It uses `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` (implicitly). Also, I'm explicitly calling `System.exit(0)` after releasing all my objects:

```
f = new JFrame("Pacman");
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        // Terminate the Game-loop:
        GameLoop.INSTANCE.stopLoop();
        // Close the application:
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

I guess that there might be an exception thrown when I close the application, but I can't find a way to get the console-output (e.g. the Stack-Trace) of a running application started with JNLP. Here's what I tried:

- Start `javaws` with the debugging parameters and connect with `jconsole` (works but I can't find any exception- or console-ouput).
- Start `javaws` with the debugging parameters and attach IntelliJ debugger to it (also works but does not give me any output)

So, how can I start the application with JNLP and get the output (written to the default out- and error-streams), as if I would do with a normal desktop application?

Comment: I'd approach it as `try { GameLoop.INSTANCE.stopLoop(); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); /* maybe pop a JOptionPane for debugging */ }
        // Close the application:
        System.exit(0);`

Comment: Could you post the code of `GameLoop.INSTANCE.stopLoop()`? From the name of this method, I think, that there might be a `wait()` or `Threa#join()` called which waits infinitely for some reason. Debugging this method is also a good idea.

Comment: @npe I'm not using the `Thread`-class, but the executer-framework. So, no `join()`- or `wait()`-calls. You might find the whole class (and the whole project) [here](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKnuth/pacman/src/70041773fdb8/src/org/ita23/pacman/game/GameLoop.java)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is their really no other way of doing this (sanely)? If the application hangs, I don't think it's going to spawn a `JOptionPane` in the same context.

Comment: *"Is their really no other way of doing this"*  I never meant to imply it was the only way.  It is just a 'quick-n-dirty' way to pause execution before shutting down.  You can dump the stack trace elements to the option pane.

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686061/how-can-i-debug-applications-under-java-web-start-jnlp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Solution #1 - Enable Java Console, and look for exceptions.

You can do it via *Java Control Panel*. Switch to *Advanced* tab, and in the *Java Console* make sure *Show console* is selected.

Then, run your application and monitor the console for exceptions. Fix the exception.

#### Solution #2 - Debug your running application (properly).

Start the Web Start app like this (for Java 1.6 and newer):

```
javaws -verbose -J-Xdebug -J-Xnoagent -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=8123 http://myserver.com/path/to/myapp.jnlp
```

If using earlier java versions (1.4.2, 1.5) set the environment variable, like this:

```
set JAVAWS_VM_ARGS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=8123"
```

and run the app via:

```
javaws http://myserver.com/path/to/myapp.jnlp
```

When the app runs:

1. Attach a debugger (Eclipse will do - use *Run* => *Debug Configurations* => *Remote Java Application*, and in *Connection Properties* panel enter the port passed in the parameters to `javaws` (in this case: `8123`).
2. Set a breakpoint inside your `windowClosing` method.
3. Try to close your application - Eclipse should break the execution on your breakpoint
4. ***Step into*** the `GameLoop.INSTANCE.stopLoop()` method to see where/when it hangs.

Don't expect to see a solutions in the console, just step through the code with a debugger - if the application hangs, it will show you where.

Comment: Nice, I now have the exception. Thanks!

Comment: Is the Xnoagent option really needed for newer Java Versions?

Comment: After launching javaws with option suggested in Solution#2, with java 7 my application launches but while starting debugger from eclipse it give error that could not connect to VM. I have specified the correct port no (8123) which was used for launching javaws. One observation was that javaws was not showing in task manager as a process which surprised me as the application was launching.

Answer (score 2):

There are times when even the console doesn't show anything, for example when there is a problem with the TLS/SSL handshake (i.e. a close_notify or handshake_failure). In these cases you need to do the following:

1. Enable the Java logs and tracing in the Java Control Panel > Advanced.
   [image: Java Control Panel: logs and tracing]
2. Enable parameters for debugging Java & launching the JNLP, there are two ways you can do it:

   2.a. Download the JNLP file and execute it from command line (the `SET` command is not required in this particular case).

   ```
   set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djavax.net.debug=all
   javaws -wait jnlp.jnlp
   ```

   2.b. Add arguments (i.e. `-Djavax.net.debug=all`) for the JVM in the Java Control Panel > Java > View (this is not required in this particular), and launch the JNLP file from browser:

   [image: Java Control Panel: jvm arguments]
3. The logs and traces are located in the `log` directory from the [Java Deployment Home](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html#gcexde) from where I paste these locations:

   a. Windows XP: `%HOME%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment`

   b. Windows 7/Vista: `%APPDATA%\..\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment`

   c. Linux/Solaris: `%HOME%/.java/deployment`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an alternative to [npe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914907/4353862) to enable the remote debug (Windows).

- Go to Control Panel;
- Click on Java, to open Java Control Panel;
- Inside of Java Control Panel, go to Java tab, and click "View";
- This will open a window with installed java versions. On runtime parameters put **"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8123,server=y,suspend=n"** (if you want to debug when application is starting, change to "suspend" to "y", that will make the application stop until an editor connect remotely);

[image: Enabling remote debug]

Afer that, configure you editor to debug remotely to the configured port (localhost:8123 in this case).