# NullPointerException on jnlp file execution on java 9

Tags: java, javafx, java-9, javafx-9

I am getting the exception below (endlessly) after run my jnlp app. I am using the java 9 early-access  release. It was working on java-8 so I thought it is about the changes on 9. I could not find anything in java-9 issues. Any idea about the reason?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.isSupported(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.isSupportedImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.isSupported(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Platform.isSupported(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.processOffer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.input.PickResultChooser.offer(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.intersects(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.pickChildrenNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region$1.doPickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper.pickNodeLocalImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.pickNodeLocal(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.access$6900(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit: It is working on java-8 perfectly. So problem should be about java-9 changes.

Comment: Try running with debug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686061/how-can-i-debug-applications-under-java-web-start-jnlp

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: What code did you try? and the stack trace seems incomplete if it does not point to the line of your code that causes the exception.

Comment: Can you submit a bug with a test case to bugs.sun.com ?

Comment: @AlanBateman it is a very big app so very hard to understand the reason. There is no link to our code in stack trace. I will try to find the exact problem.